# Android: would be a problem to not shutDown the ExecutorService?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, android-lifecycle, executorservice

I have a library instanced at app starts and lives during entire app lifeCycle. In this library there is an newSingleThreadExecutor.
If I never call the shutDown on the executorService what will happen when I will close the app from Android Recents Screen ?

The app process rest alive because there are an active executor with a thread ?

The following ideas resolve the no shutdown issue ?

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool() {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                  60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                  new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

I have seen that inside firebase crashlytics there is a CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker, that write the logs.
How does firebase shutdown the CrashlyticsBackgroundWorker when the app closed ???

Answer (score 1):

Generally, unless you are running a foreground service, swiping away the app from Recents will kill the application's process.  Killing the process terminates all threads and process state, including the `ExecutorService`.

Thus, there's no need to explictly `shutDown` the service if it is intended to be running as long as the app is.  It won't stop the system from killing the process.